# Writing a .bat file to stop and start service on cycle times?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a .bat file to stop and start a service. This is easy and I write it as follow:

```
net stop file name 
if %errorlevel% == 2 echo Access Denied - Could not stop service
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo Service stopped successfully
echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%

net start file name 
if %errorlevel% == 2 echo Access Denied - Could not stop service
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo Service stopped successfully
echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%
```

but the service takes long to stop so does not always stop and start. I would like to stop and start this service every hour and 30 min but I also want to make sure that the service does stop and start.

can someone help me with this thank you

Comment: Use a scheduled task to perform actions based upon a schedule!

Comment: Use the `SC` command to query the state of the service.